# Sign Convention for Energy Methods in Vibration Analysis

Tags: dynamics, vibration, energy, stiffness

Find the equivalent spring stiffness of the system below.

[image]

I was able to solve it using Newton's second law and got the result below.

$$ k_{eq} = \frac{mgl}{2} - \frac{k_1 l^2}{16} - k_2 l^2$$

However, I also wanted to solve it by the Energy Method, which led to the following answer

$$ k_{eq} = \frac{mgl}{2} + \frac{k_1 l^2}{16} + k_2 l^2$$

It is clear that I **do not understand** how to apply the proper **sign convention** when using Energy Methods. Could someone please provide me an explanation on how to consider it and some material for further reading? I could not clearly understand based on my searches.

Comment: Which direction do you class as positive? to the right? or to the left? analyse for both and see.

Comment: Usually when books are assessing systems with Energy Methods they do not go into much sign convention details. I wanted to get a general explanation so I can apply not only to this case, which can be verified from Newton's law, but to more complex cases.

Comment: The Lagrangian produces a consistent solution for all cases, and is defined as L = T - V (T = kinetic energy, V = potential energy).  The usual sign convention assumes a right-handed coordinate system (positive to the right and upwards).  That should give you the signs in the first equation (haven't checked myself).

Comment: The thing is, when finding an equivalent spring stiffness we only use potential energy. I do not understand the sign convention for potential energy in these cases. For the system you are right, the Lagrangian is that one, which includes kinetic energy.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you say *Energy Methods*, it is not clear what you mean. It would be better to see your derivation so that we can point out the mistake. Moreover, I wouldn't say the equivalent spring stiffness $k_{eq} = \frac{mgl}{2} - \frac{k_1 l^2}{16} - k_2 l^2$ but $k_{eq} = -\frac{mgl}{2} + \frac{k_1 l^2}{16} + k_2 l^2$ because for $\theta$ in any direction, the opposing moment must be about the the other direction ($-$ sign).

How would I solve the problem? Of course, without FBDs, using the **Bond Graph** method. It is an energy method. This is how it goes:

$$\text{Total Power}=\sum_{elements}{\text{Effort} \cdot \text{Flow}}=0 \tag{1}$$

where **effort**s are generalized forces (force, moment, voltage, etc.) and **flow**s are generalized speeds (speed, angular speed, current, etc.).

You have four elements in your system (you can think of the rod as a point mass and an inertia). Note that $\text{Effort} \cdot \text{Flow}$ must be negative if they are in the opposite directions.

$$\text{Spring 1: }\text{Effort} \cdot \text{Flow}=(-k_1\frac{l}{4}\sin \theta)(\frac{l}{4}\dot{\theta}\cos \theta) \tag{2}$$
$$\text{Spring 2: }\text{Effort} \cdot \text{Flow}=(-k_1l\sin \theta)(l\dot{\theta}\cos \theta) \tag{3}$$
$$\text{Point Mass: }\text{Effort} \cdot \text{Flow}=(-mg)(-\frac{l}{2}\dot{\theta}\sin \theta) \tag{4}$$
$$\text{Inertia: }\text{Effort} \cdot \text{Flow}=(-I\ddot{\theta})(\dot{\theta}) \tag{5}$$

Add Equations 2, 3, 4 and 5 as shown in Equation 1 and assume $\sin \theta \approx \theta$ and $\cos \theta \approx 1$ (small $\theta$).

$$-I\ddot{\theta}\dot{\theta}+\left(mg\frac{l}{2}-k_1\frac{l^2}{4}-k_2l^2\right)\dot{\theta} \theta=0 \tag{6}$$

Divide both sides by $-\dot{\theta}$

$$I\ddot{\theta}+\left(-mg\frac{l}{2}+k_1\frac{l^2}{4}+k_2l^2\right)\theta=0 \tag{7}$$

The equivalent spring constant is

$$k_\text{eq}=\left(-mg\frac{l}{2}+k_1\frac{l^2}{4}+k_2l^2\right) \tag{8}$$

The Bond Graph method is a general method for modeling systems that contain electrical, hydraulic, mechanic, and other types of subsystems with energy methods. Even though it is not very popular in literature, it increases one's understanding of the connection between physics and math. I personally use Bond Graph methods for modeling and simulating the systems. For further study, see  *Karnopp, D., Margolis, D. L., & Rosenberg, R. C. (2012). System Dynamics: Modeling, Simulation, and Control of Mechatronic Systems. Wiley*.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I never heard about the Bond Graph, but it got me curious. I will check on the source that you provide (thanks for that too). Also, I have to agree about the signs, you got me thinking there.

Comment: bond not bong in bold above

Answer (score 0):

When the bar is rotating it does work on the springs, so the potential energy stored in the springs is negative relative to the potential energy of the bar.

Equating the potential energy of the translational springs to that of the rotational spring, all expressed in $\theta$ and assuming $\theta$ is small:
$$\frac{1}{2}k_1\left(\frac{\ell\theta}{4}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}k_2(\ell\theta)^2=\frac{1}{2}k_\theta\theta^2\hspace{1cm}\Longrightarrow\hspace{1cm} k_\theta=\frac{k_1\ell^2}{4^2}+k_2\ell^2$$
If we want an equation of motion of the form, $J\ddot{\theta}+k_\theta\theta=0$, to represent the dynamics of the bar, then we need to incoorporate the torque from the displaced mass into the spring constant. This torque can be written
$$T_m=\frac{mg\ell\sin(\theta)}{2}\approx\frac{mg\ell\theta}{2},  \hspace{1cm}\theta<15^\circ$$
So, our equivalent system can be written
$$J\ddot{\theta}=T_m-k_\theta\theta\approx \frac{mg\ell}{2}\theta-k_\theta\theta=k_\text{eq}\theta$$
This gives
$$k_\text{eq}=\frac{mg\ell}{2}-\frac{k_1\ell^2}{4^2}-k_2\ell^2$$
I.e. we get a representation of the dynamics of the bar by the equation
$$J\ddot{\theta}=k_\text{eq}\theta,\hspace{1cm}J=\frac{m\ell^2}{4}$$

Comment: Just to let you know that I am checking your answer, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for helping! I did understand now why it is negative. Unlike kinetic energy, which is always positive, when assessing potential energy I should pay more attention to which 'datum' I am using as a reference. Kind of a silly mistake, but necessary.